# can't create startup disk in ubuntu when selecting fedora iso

Tags: usb, fedora, startup-disk-creator

I can't select a fedora image to create a bootable usb stick. It works with ubutu and gnome ubuntu but not with fedora. Does the ubuntu startup creator only work with ubuntu isos?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried another app to do it? [UNetBootIn](https://unetbootin.github.io/) is a good one (and does not require any installation, just download, unpack, launch and go). I remember the same issue when I'm tried to create a Live USB with a non-Ubuntu distro.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu Startup disk maker able to create Debian based OS like **Lubuntu,Xubuntu,Kubuntu,Kali,Debian and Ubuntu** and others similar "Debian bases distros". Not support distros like fedora,Cent OS and Open SUSE.

[Reason described well here](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1188721/3)