# Are there any know errors in the Ubuntu 16.04 bootable USB sticks that we create with the disk creator?

Tags: boot, live-usb, 16.04, startup-disk-creator, checksums

I have just created a bootable USB stick with the new ubuntu 16.04 iso. The md5 check gives me that everything is fine with the iso I make it from, but when I check for errors on the USB pendrive. I get a message that there are two errors.

Is there a way to find out what errors I have on the pendrive and how to fix them?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I have decided to do the same with a linux mint iso file that previously I used for an installation (and back then it didnt give me a hard time, nor any errors). After the MD5 check (which gave me no errors either) I installed it on a pendrive using the startup disk creator (usb-creator-gtk). When I checked the pendrie for erros....I got 68 errors. So, something has gone during the installation (using usb-creator-gtk).

So, I decided to run the usb-creator-gtk from the terminal and check for any error messages. During the installation I get this message:

[image]

By the way,before the installation I had tried to erase the USB pendrive's content (because for some reason in the list 2 different things appear with the same name. see image.)
[image]

So, I can easily erase the 1st one, but the second one gives me the following error message:
[image]

I am wondering if something is not okay with the actual pendrive.

Gparted gives me this info on it:

[image]

Any ideas what the solution could be?

Comment: I think if you press an F key during boot you can see verbose messages.

Comment: I have just tried F5 after the error message popped up, but it just restarts the whole thing. I am wondering what keep lets me see the messages in the background.

Comment: You'll have to press it before it gets to that error.

Answer (score 0):

I reported a problem here [can't create startup disk in ubuntu when selecting fedora iso](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761123/cant-create-startup-disk-in-ubuntu-when-selecting-fedora-iso)

and the following error dialog box from Startup Disk Maker

[Sartup Disk Maker error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iqRI.png)

Comment: I have created a disk using Rufus in windows. It doesnt end up giving me the 2 errors. I still believe that it is something with usb-creator-gtk. In Rufus a message popped up that 2 files were missing. I hope someone savvy looks into this soon.